# Identify clusters of a new data set using cluster information of a different data set?

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis

I have a time-series that has 3 dimensions, I clustered every point taking into account 3 dimensions and the correlation between them and also serial correlation of each point with its adjacent point. My question is how I can use the information that I have from these clusters and identify clusters of a similar data set?

Answer (score 0):

Train a classifier on your first clustering.

Then use the classifier to predict the new label.

A popular choice is the nearest neighbor classifier.